# Responsive - How to suppose A window with particular size on a div with other size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div with size : 400px x 600px

Now i wanna set a iframe (1200px x 800px) into parent div like this picture or image:

http://ami.responsivedesign.is

[See in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vexn.jpg) 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: i did not understood what you want.

Comment: I need to show iframe (1200px x 400px) in a div (400px x 600px),

You can see it on top in the :  website http://ami.responsivedesign.is

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/YyC30

@DurgeshDangi 
How easily can i do it ? :(

Comment: Don't vandalize your post, as to your question... you can't delete question since there is an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the functionality that you are looking for, if im not mistaken, is CSS3 Media Queries

Media queries are used so that you can make elements of your have different css properties.

For example you can have a div with the height of 100px when the screen width is 1366px or have the div's height to 200px when the screen width is 1920px

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: when i tried to set iframe ( 1200px ) then i had a problem like this picture
http://imgur.com/a/0QQD8

Comment: Set overflow:hidden; or overflow:scroll; of the parent div

Comment: @C J 
http://imgur.com/a/YyC30 I wanna it like this picture
If i set width iframe 100% , the width of iframe exactly = width of parent not = 1200px 

 How easily can i do it ?